# CakePHP - How to perform unit conversions?

Tags: cakephp

How to perform a unit convertion in a nice way with CakePHP?
I have all mesurment values saved in "mm" in the database, if the user has another perfered mesurmentsystem then "metric" i need to convert and display the mesurments in that system.

Comment: I would create a custom helper. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html

Comment: Yup, a helper is probably the best way, assuming that users cannot *insert* new data in the database and this is for presentation only.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The users have to be able to save some mesurments data in their own system and i need it to be converted to "mm" before saving into the database. Any input on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a lib class in /Lib where you put the basic conversion stuff.
Then you either use it as Lib directly anywhere in your app (model etc) or you can extend it as a helper for your view level.

Check out how the core does it with CakeNumber and NumberHelper, CakeTime and TimeHelper and String and TextHelper.
Analogously should you code your measurement conversion.

Comment: and if its something you do more than once for beforeSave() or afterFind() etc you can even use the Lib in a MeasurementBehavior etc.